# Could not connect to a primary node for replica set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a MongoDB running on a EC2 (AWS) instance where my production app is running from and everything seems fine. On the same db, I also have a development db which I use locally, however I had a problem with my Mac and got a new one. On the new one I cannot connect to the db using a command like: `rails c` and `User.count` as I get this error:

```
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure: Could not connect to a primary node for replica set #<Moped::Cluster:70300606784060 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>
```

Yet the production app works fine without hiccups. This is only happening on my new local machine. And yes, I have checked whether the config on the EC2 security group but the security group is allowing my IP, which hasn't changed with the new machine.

Any suggestions on what I might be missing?

**EDIT**

Here's my `mongoid.yml` file:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: mongodb://some_ip:some_port/production
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false

test:
  sessions:
    default:
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      database: mrc_test
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false

testing:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: mongodb://some_ip:some_port/testing
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false

production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: mongodb://some_ip:some_port/production
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

Comment: `resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017` So it looks like you are missing the remote connection string completely.

Comment: @NeilLunn you mean on the mongoid file itself?

Comment: I thought you said this was "remote" on EC2? What are there "localhost" entries in your config? Clearly the "test" configuration is being picked up since the error shows an attempt to connect to `localhost`.

Comment: @NeilLunnn I see what you mean however I get the same result when I try `rails c RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: Then you have something wrong and it would seem logical that the configuration is not being picked up at all. Any MongoDB driver will "default" to connecting to `localhost`, where you clearly are not running a MongoDB instance. You might look for any indication that the file is in the wrong location or has a parse error that is stopping it being read.

Comment: I believe I've found the issue. It was an error within the mongoid config file and instead of the error being raised it still tried to connect. I've recreated the mongoid file and now everything seems to work fine. Thanks for your help!